# Integral of fraction on circle

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Compute $\int_{|z|=2}\dfrac{1}{z^2-1}dz$ where the circle $|z|=2$ is oriented counterclockwise.

I want to use the formula $\int f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$. So I parametrize the curve by $z(t)=2(\cos t+i\sin t)$ for $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

The integral becomes $\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{4(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t)-1}\cdot(-2\sin t+2i\cos t)dt$.

This is a mess. How would I integrate it?

Comment: If I were you I would use [Residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to calculate this integral.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Interesting, but in the book I'm reading (Ahlfors), in the section in which the exercise appears, the book hasn't got to Residue theorem yet. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition? You do *not* want to do it by parametrizing explicitly.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure, I can do $\dfrac{1}{z^2-1}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac1{z-1}-\dfrac1{z+1}\right)$ and integrate each part. But what do you mean by not parametrizing explicitly?

Comment: I mean that you can do each of those without parametrizing the curve and doing a real integral. I was thinking that Ahlfors had discussed homotopy invariance by this point, so that you could replace the circle $|z|=2$ with circles centered around $1$ and $-1$ respectively. But, indeed, Cauchy's Theorem is in the next section, as well. So now I'm thinking he wants you to realize the function $f(z)=1/(z^2-1)$ has an analytic primitive in the region $|z|>1$, since he's discussed branches of $\log$ already.

Comment: Oh, on second thought, you can easily do the partial fractioned version by parametrizing. Just keep it in complex terms: $z=2e^{i\theta}$, $dz=\dots\,d\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C:|z|=2$

$z(\theta)=2e^{i\theta}$ where $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$

$z'(\theta)=2ie^{i\theta}d\theta$

$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2-1}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{(2e^{i\theta})^2-1}$

let $u=2e^{i\theta}\implies \frac{du}{i}=2e^{i\theta}d\theta$

By partial fractions:

$\int \frac{du}{u^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}[ln(2e^{i\theta}-1)-ln(2e^{i\theta}-1)]$ evaluated at $0$ and $2\pi$

and $2e^{i2\pi}=2=2e^{i0}$ so we have $\frac{1}{2}[ln(2-1)-ln(2-1)-ln(2-1)+ln(2-1)]=0$.

Thus $\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2-1}=0$.